# (Notepad++) Replace with regular expression: FixedText(xxx[yyy],whatever) to FixedText(yyy, xxx[yyy],whatever)

Tags: regex

Sorry for not knowing the basics of regular expressions and asking this, but I couldn't get to it myself.

I need to replace all expressions `PlayerTextDrawSetString(SSbank[playerid],strBank)`

with `PlayerTextDrawSetString(playerid,SSbank[playerid],strBank)`

,

```
PlayerTextDrawSetString(SWant[someid],strWant)
```

with `PlayerTextDrawSetString(someid,SWant[someid],strWant)`

etc.

I can find such expressions with `PlayerTextDrawSetString+\(+.+\[+.+\]`, but I can't replace them with that (\1, \2, \3 etc. return empty symbol).

I tried different search strings, but in all cases I get nothing on \1, \2, etc.

Could you please write the correct regex for me?
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: P.S. I will be back in several hours, will mark the best answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these expressions:

Search:

```
(PlayerTextDrawSetString\()(\w+\[)(\w+)
```

Replace:

```
\1\3,\2\3
```

Comment: Doesn't find a match. You'd need a `+` after the first `\w`.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ ahhh thanks. I could have sworn I put one in there :/.  Edited. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The first two examples work.

Search Pattern 1:

```
SSbank\[([^\]]+)\]
```

Replacement Pattern  1:

```
\1,SSbank[\1]
```

Search Pattern 2:

```
SWant\[([^\]]+)\]
```

Replacement Pattern 2:

```
\1,SWant[\1]
```

To go all out if you have a lot of these similar patterns you can do this:

Total Replacement Search:

```
\((\w+)\[([^\]]+)\]
```

Total Replacement String (yes the first slash is needed... a bug maybe?):

```
\(\2,\1[\2]
```

**Look behind is apparently broken.**

I tried to give Notepad++ a shot with the positive look behind but the replacement fails even though the match happens. Here's the pattern:

```
(?<=\()(\w+)\[([^\]]+)\]
```

My attempted replacement (doesn't replace anything in Notepad++ v6.3.2):

```
\2,\1[\2]
```